# jquery datepicker lost interactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datetimepicker

I'm working on a php-html-javascript project and I'm really going crazy with this problem.
The project uses jquery datetime picker and everything is fine (the datetime picker works on other pages and also in the "affected ones"), but when I'm trying to use it on a dynamically created element the date time picker loses interactivity: can't click it or change year/month, it only closes when there's a click on another element. It doesn't even trigger the "onSelect" event so I can't use it.

OTHER INFORMATIONS:
- The div associated is in the page (DOM element) but is cloned as a new div ($.clone())
- The datetime picker is associated with the element when the div is fully created (callback), so there is no possibility of not-loaded element
- The datetime picker displays on click but isn't interactive.

I tried for days but I can't solve this. Hope you all can help... Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what to post because the code is the minimal code of every application with that object... I can't post a complete example becaus there are too many objects in the page and i can't post a link to the project... It's just an intellectual request.

Answer (score 1):

As far i know the problem is occurring because of [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).If we use clone with true as the argument then the events and properties associated with the old element copies to cloned element. May be when you click on the calendar check whether the date is been displayed on the first text box. If it is so then there must be problem with the cloning.